# Stream causes OutOfMemoryError in Scala

Tags: scala, stream

When I use a List it works correctly but when I create an infinite Stream

```
def foo = {
    val s = Stream.from(1)
    s.flatMap(x =>
                s.flatMap(y =>
                    s.flatMap(z => f(x, y, z))))
}
```

I'm getting a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when I call

```
foo.take(10)
```

As relates to f

```
    def f(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) = {
       if(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) == Math.pow(z, 2) )
       else None
    }
```

Initially, I thought that it will be evaluated only when I would call it for these 10 elements but know I'm not sure. I'm getting the same problem with `Iterator.from(1)`
Any help please. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How can you flatmap on every element in the stream. Its infinite! You will run out of memory. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You code works for me. Please post the _exact_ code you're using, including the definition of `f`. Note `foo.take(10)` returns a Stream, so we also need to know what you're doing with that value

Comment: I updated my question. The returned stream is what I expect. Thank you Paul

Comment: @OK, so that fails, where an f that just returns Some((x,y,z)) doesn't. So it's your use of x > y, which is forcing the evaluation of the Stream.

Comment: How can I not evaluate it? Is there any way to use lazy here? Thank you very much Paul

Comment: @jimakos17 just out of curiosity, what is the use of this function ?

Comment: It seems that this is related to the generation of stream. In your stream first `z`s are growing. So you will get (1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,1,3), .... . In such a sequence of tuples there is no tuple satisfying `x > y` so even if you don't get `OutOfMemory`, computation will be executed forever. One way is to generate the stream in a different way (to grow uniformly on `x`, `y`, and `z`). But what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to generate triples in which the first member is greater than the second.  To start, let's generate some pairs like that:

```
scala> def natNums = Iterator from 1
natNums: Iterator[Int]

scala> def foo = for { x <- natNums; y <- 1 until x } yield (x,y)
foo: Iterator[(Int, Int)]

scala> (foo take 15).toList
res4: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,1), (3,1), (3,2), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (5,1), (5,2), (5,3), (5,4), (6,1), (6,2), (6,3), (6,4), (6,5))
```

Am I on the right track?

OK, now you want to add in a third member to the tuple.  Well, if we similarly constrain z to be less than y, it works fine:

```
scala> def foo = for { x <- natNums; y <- 1 until x; z <- 1 until y } yield (x,y,z)
foo: Iterator[(Int, Int, Int)]

scala> (foo take 15).toList
res1: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((3,2,1), (4,2,1), (4,3,1), (4,3,2), (5,2,1), (5,3,1), (5,3,2), (5,4,1), (5,4,2), (5,4,3), (6,2,1), (6,3,1), (6,3,2), (6,4,1), (6,4,2))
```

But if z is unconstrained, I don't understand what you want the program to do.  Just drawing z from natNums turns the CPU into a toaster:

```
scala> def foo = for { x <- natNums; y <- 1 until x; z <- natNums } yield (x,y,z)
foo: Iterator[(Int, Int, Int)]

scala> (foo take 15).toList
^C
```

Can you give us the output you are expecting?

UPDATE: Ah!  Pythagorean triples -- how fun!

Here is a simple generator for what I'll call "raw" Pythagorean triples because it includes multiples which need to be filtered out.  For example, (6,8,10) should not be counted as a Pythagorean triple since it is a multiple of (3,4,5).  I'll leave that for you since I think what was blocking you was just the part about generating the numbers in the first place.  Feel free to ask for help with that in another StackOverflow question if you need it.

```
scala> def rawPythagTriples =
   for { c <- Iterator from 1; a <- 1 until c; b <- a until c if a*a + b*b == c*c }
     yield (a,b,c)
rawPythagTriples: Iterator[(Int, Int, Int)]

scala> (rawPythagTriples take 10).toList
res2: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((3,4,5), (6,8,10), (5,12,13), (9,12,15), (8,15,17), (12,16,20), (7,24,25), (15,20,25), (10,24,26), (20,21,29))
```

Note that we begin with the hypotenuse, thus constraining `a` and `b`.  By the way, you could make some minor optimizations, e.g. starting `c` at 5, `a` at 2, and `b` at `a+1`.

Comment: Thank you AmigoNico. The output I expect is the Pythagorean triples. I'm sorry I didn't clarify this from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This works in REPL:

```
def foo = {
  val s = Stream.from(1)
  s.flatMap(x =>
    s.flatMap(y =>
      s.flatMap(z => List(x,y,z))))
}

scala> foo.take(15) mkString ", "
res24: String = 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 5
```

Your f(x,y,z) must return a type that extends a subclass of GenTraversableOnce[?].

Comment: Yes, that does, but the definition of `f` in the updated question does not.